# different search result by changing var to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

My search result becomes case sensitive when I change var to IEnumerable; consider below code:

the code below returns both cases with RA or ra:

```
var result = from x in dataBase.tableName 
             select x;
result = result.Where(x => x.id.Contains("ra"));
```

the code below returns only cases with ra and not RA:

```
IEnumerable result = from x in dataBase.tableName 
                     select x;
result = result.Where(x => x.id.Contains("ra"));
```

Could someone help and explain me what is going on? shouldn't the result be similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case, `var` will be an `IQueryable<T>` - which means your `Where` call will be to `Queryable.Where` (after converting your lambda expression to an expression tree). The filter ends up being executed in the database, where I suspect your field is case-insensitive (and so searching is case-insensitive).

In the second case, you've got an `IEnumerable<T>`, so your `Where` call will be to `Enumerable.Where` (after converting your lambda expression to a delegate). The filter ends up being executed in .NET code instead - where `Contains` is always case-sensitive.

Basically, LINQ is a leaky abstraction - yes, it would be lovely if the same filter gave the same results in all situations, but that's unrealistic. Learn where the leaks are, and act accordingly - LINQ is still a huge boon :)

Answer (score 7):

Your `result` variable is not an `IEnumerable` - it is an `IQueryable`.

The result is changing when you manually change the type to `IEnumerable`since you now do the following `Contains` query with Linq to Objects and not on the database with Linq to Entities (or Linq to SQL).

With `IEnumerable` your query is using your lambda expression, bringing each result from the DB into memory and executing the case sensitive `Contains()` extension method.

With `IQueryable` your query is using an expression tree and will try to create a corresponding database query with your `Contains` query which happens to be case insensitive (most likely a SQL `LIKE` query).

Just making the implicit type explicit as `IQueryable` will fix your problem.